# Can I use blendFunc in CCAnimation?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Recently I need improve my visual effect of my app by using `blendFunc` in `CCSprite`. But I don't know how to use it in `CCAnimation`. Here is my implementation:

```
CCSprite * test=[CCSprite node];
test.position=CGPointMake(100, 200);
test.scale=3;
test.blendFunc=(ccBlendFunc){GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE};//it's not working
[scene addChild:test];

self.textureArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int x=0;x<=18;x++){        
   [self.textureArray addObject:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithTextureFilename:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"skill_01_%d.png",x] rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 91, 61)]];      
}

CCAnimation * animation=[CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:self.textureArray delay:0.1];

[test runAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation]];
```

But the `blendFuc` is not working for this case, and only `CCSprite` can set `blendFunc`. What can I do if I need all the frames in my animation has the blendFunc's effect?

By the way, I tried to use a timer to animate the frames manually:

```
self.skllTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(animating:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)animating:(NSTimer *)t{

    CCSprite * tesx=[self.textureArray objectAtIndex:f];//f is a increasing value   
    CCSprite * ok =[CCSprite spriteWithTexture:tesx.texture];
    ok.blendFunc=(ccBlendFunc){GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE};
    [self.aniLayer removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:NO];
    [self.aniLayer addChild:ok];

}
```

I get what I want in this way, but it's not effecient, I think there must be some better way to do it.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I've found that it's caused by

```
-(void) updateBlendFunc
{
    NSAssert( ! _batchNode, @"CCSprite: updateBlendFunc doesn't work when the sprite is rendered using a CCSpriteBatchNode");

    // it is possible to have an untextured sprite
    if( !_texture || ! [_texture hasPremultipliedAlpha] ) {
        _blendFunc.src = GL_SRC_ALPHA;
        _blendFunc.dst = GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA;
        [self setOpacityModifyRGB:NO];
    } else {
        _blendFunc.src = CC_BLEND_SRC;//here
        _blendFunc.dst = CC_BLEND_DST;//and here
        [self setOpacityModifyRGB:YES];
    }


}
```

Every time when CCSprite updates it's displayFrame, this function will change it's own _blendFunc. I don't know why it's like this, but after I removing the following two lines:

```
//_blendFunc.src = CC_BLEND_SRC;//here
//_blendFunc.dst = CC_BLEND_DST;//and here
```

The problem solved. Can I fix cocos2d like this? I hope there is no bug caused by my change.
Please someone tell me an exact answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code snippet wouldn't work since the sprite you created doesn't have any texture and CCSprite doesn't update the blendFunc if there is no texture associated with it. What you should rather do is this.

> ```
> // add sprite frames to the sprite frame cache
> CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:spriteFramesArra[0]];
> sprite.blendFunc = newBlendFunc;
> [sprite runAnimation:animation];
> ```

Since the animation frames use the same texture and we set the required texture on the sprite after associating the texture with it once the animation runs it would be correctly set and updated.

Comment: That works for me, thanks :) and what's more I found,
if you'd like to play another animation, just set the sprite's frame with the first frame of the animation, and set blendFunc.